# how to disable colored display when listing tag targets in vi?

Tags: vi, ctags

This has always been a nuisance to me.
In a new PC for experiment, I set syntax=off so normal vi doesn't show things in color.
But when I press g+] to list up tag targets(using ctags), I see the tagged locations. The file is in dark blue color so it's hard to see unless I look closer, with my glasses off.
How can I prevent vi showing the tag list in color too?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about Vim/Neovim, not original Vi.

Even though syntax is off, Vim still uses color scheme and all such stuff. In particular, some listing items are coloured. You cannot avoid that, except making colors more appropriate. Maybe switching to another color scheme, or maybe directly reassigning offending color groups, e.g.

```
:hi! link Directory Normal
```